# is there a way to check whether a row has a value or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, xlrd, xlwt

There are 2 columns inside an excel file. One has the name of the courses and the next one has the grade that the student scored in that course. Some courses don't have grades in front of them. Is there a way to check if that cell is empty or not?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your data, everything needed to answer this should be included in the question itself. See how to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you. I did.

Answer (score 0):

you can check it mabe using search with re

example:

```
from re import search
```

the file are like that example as column

```
+---------+--------+
| Student | Score  |
|---------|--------|        
|         |        |
| John    |   9    |
|         |        |
| Katty   |   7    |
|         |        |
| Alexnder|   8    |
|         |        |
|         |        |
| Bob     |        | #Empty
+------------------+
```

Example Only , I wanna Search the Score Of Bob
i will open the file

```
f = open('filename', 'r').readlines()
for d in f:
   column = d.rstrip()
```

now i will start Search the Result of Bob

```
   g = search(r'| Bob     |   (.*)    |', column)
   result = g.group(1)
   if result = '':
      print "Result Of Bob Is Empty"
   else:
      print "Result Of Bob Is : " + result
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a dummy xlsx with the following values:

```
Course  | Grade
Maths   |
English | A
Science | B
```

Using [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), and assuming the second column in the excel file is the grades and it only has one worksheet:

```
>>> from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
>>> wb = load_workbook('Grades.xlsx')
>>> ws = wb.active
>>> for row in range(2,ws.max_row+1):
...     if not ws[row][1].value:
...             print([x.value for x in ws[row]])
...
[u'Maths', None]
```

and with [xlrd](https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/) using an xls file with the same values:

```
>>> import xlrd
>>> wb = xlrd.open_workbook('Grades.xls')
>>> ws = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
>>> for row in range(1, ws.nrows):
...     if not ws.cell_value(row, 1):
...             print([ws.cell_value(row,0),ws.cell_value(row,1)])
...
[u'Maths', u'']
```